# How to enforce policy without tag no job will run

Tags: azure, gitlab, terraform

We are using gitlab pipeline to spin infrastructure like VM/Service bus and other resources through terraform in Azure cloud. Many time Developers forget to tag what purpose they spin off resource. Due to lack of this info, we are unable to find resources and their purpose.

Is there any way in gitlab pipeline through variable or any other way without tag pipeline will fail? Like enforcement to use tag while spinning of any infrastructure through gitlab pipeline. 
I am looking for any configuration or enforcement policy in gitlab

Comment: ok, where the tag needs to be? on the build\release? on the resource in azure?

Comment: Let I write my question in a more specific way,
I have a file called terraform. tfvars ,  as a best practice we have to mention ENV variable (tags_environment = "test")and than we trigger pipeline by gitlab, terraform (init, plan and apply)
 
I want to enforce some policy while creating any Resource in Azure by pipeline (Or Manually), without tagging no resource can be spin. If  tags_environment is absent pipeline must fail. 
This policy can be placed anywhere  in Azure(RG level) or gilab

Comment: You can add a policy in azure subscription level. Pipeline or Terraform is noting to do with this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/enforce-tag-on-resource-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Azure policy for that. Enforce tag:

```
{
   "properties": {
      "displayName": "Enforce tag and its value",
      "policyType": "BuiltIn",
      "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value.",
      "parameters": {
         "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
            }
         },
         "tagValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Value of the tag, such as headquarter"
            }
         }
      },
      "policyRule": {
         "if": {
            "not": {
               "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
               "equals": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
            }
         },
         "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
         }
      }
   },
   "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62",
   "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
   "name": "1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62"
}
```

Links:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/enforce-tag-value
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/enforce-tag-on-resource-groups